# neo4j - cypher query how to check StoreID

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to figure out how to identify a database uniquely via a cypher query.  I understand the StoreID along with the KernelStartTime kernel parameters with do this... can I access those parameters or something else via a cypher query?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what your data looks like?  I don't know what StoreID refers to or how it relates.

Answer (score 1):

The Cypher language currently only exposes the graph data, not metadata about the DB instance.

As a workaround, you may want to store uniquely identifying information in a singleton node (i.e., a node that is the only one having a special label) in each DB instance. *This tactic will not work, however, if you want to use Cypher to distinguish between the DB instances in a HA cluster.*

Answer (score 0):

While technically I'm not sure if this is strictly a Cypher query or not, it is possible by querying the jmx interface through Cypher. Try this:

```
CALL dbms.queryJmx("org.neo4j:instance=*,name=Kernel") YIELD attributes
RETURN attributes.StoreId.value, attributes.KernelStartTime.value
```

Or this to list all jmx objects:

```
CALL dbms.queryJmx("org.neo4j:*")
```